# how does this select query works with that output

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got a doubt, how these select query works,

`select 6 | 7`

Answer is 7

how??

guys help me

Thanks to all.

Comment: It gets all the 1 from those 2 numbers as binary.

Answer (score 2):

| is the bitwise OR.

6 or 7 == 7

0110 | 0111 == 0111

Answer (score 2):

Its bitwise `Or`

```
6: 110  (base2)
7: 111  (base2)
OR =====   
   111 = 7
```

Similarly, `Select 6|8` will return `14`

```
8: 1000  (base2)
6: 0110  (base2)
OR ====
   1110 = 14
```

To do it in your head, if you are unfamiliar, line up the bits and the OR operator simply means the bit is set in one or the other (or both) of the original terms.

Had it been `Select 6 & 7` this would mean AND the bits (the bits are set in both)

select 6 & 7

```
6:  110
7:  111
AND ===
    110 = 6
```